# No Model Summary For GLMs in Pyspark / SparkML

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm familiarizing myself with `Pyspark` and `SparkML` at the moment. To do so I use the titanic dataset to train a GLM for predicting the 'Fare' in that dataset.

I'm following closely the Spark documentation. I do get a working model (which I call `glm_fare`) but when I try to assess the trained model using `summary` I get the following error message:

*RuntimeError: No training summary available for this GeneralizedLinearRegressionModel*

Why is this?

The code for training was as such:

```
glm_fare = GeneralizedLinearRegression(
            labelCol="Fare", 
            featuresCol="features", 
            predictionCol='prediction',
            family='gamma',
            link='log',
            weightCol='wght',
            maxIter=20
            )
    glm_fit = glm_fare.fit(training_df)

    glm_fit.summary
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone comes across this question, I ran into this problem as well and it seems that this error occurs when the Hessian matrix is not invertible. This matrix is used in the maximization of the likelihood for estimating the coefficients.

The matrix is not invertible if one of the eigenvalues is 0, which occurs when there is multicollinearity in your variables. This means that one of the variables can be predicted with a linear combination of the other variables. Consequently, the effect of each of the variables cannot be identified with any significance.

A possible solution would be to find the variables that are (multi)collinear and remove one of them from the regression. Note however that multicollinearity is only a problem if you want to interpret the coefficients and not when the model is used for prediction.

Answer (score 0):

It is documented possibly there could be no `summary` available for a model in [GeneralizedLinearRegressionModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/GeneralizedLinearRegressionModel.html#summary--) docs.

#### However you can do an initial check to avoid the error:

`glm_fit.hasSummary()` which is a public boolean method.
Using it as

```
if glm_fit.hasSummary():
    print(glm_fit.summary)
```

Here is a direct like to the [Pyspark source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/regression.html#GeneralizedLinearRegressionModel)
and the [GeneralizedLinearRegressionTrainingSummary class source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/GeneralizedLinearRegression.scala#L1057) and where the [error](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/GeneralizedLinearRegression.scala#L1571) is thrown

Comment: Hi @pissall, thanks for your answer - I've seen this in the documentation as well. Is there somewhere a good documentation on when a summary is available? That's not very obvious to me at the moment...

Comment: @GluonCollision Maybe we need to see the training data for that?

Comment: The dataset is the kaggle Titanic dataset. Basically: '''df=titanic.dropna().filter(titanic.Fare>0)'''. Then I OneHot encode the categorical vars and MinMaxScale the numerical ones. The onehot / minmaxscaled features go into the model.

Comment: @GluonCollision Will have to try that out myself to reproduce the error. I might take time to come back with an answer but I'll definitely try.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your input variables for one hot encoder starts from 0.
One error I made that caused summary not created is, I put quarter(1,2,3,4) directly to one hot encoder, and get a vector of length 4, and one column is 0. I converted quarter to 0,1,2,3 and problem solved.