# RuntimeError: No training summary available for this LogisticRegressionModel

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I am trying to evaluate my Logistic Regression model, going to get the "bestModel" based on the k-fold cross validation, which is also fully upgraded on the whole `train_df`.
This is my Pipeline:

```
# This function defines the general pipeline for logistic regression
def lr_pipeline(train, 
                numerical_feature, 
                target_variable, 
                with_std=True,
                with_mean=True,
                k_fold=5):

    from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, StandardScaler
    from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
    from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
    from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
    from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

    # Create stages list
    stages = [] 

    # Create the logistic regression transformer
    log_reg = LogisticRegression(featuresCol="word2vect", labelCol="label", maxIter=100, weightCol="classWeigth") 

    # Add the logistic regression transformer to the pipeline stages (i.e., the last one)
    stages += [log_reg]

    # Set up the pipeline
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)

    # We use a ParamGridBuilder to construct a grid of parameters to search over.
    # A CrossValidator requires an Estimator, a set of Estimator ParamMaps, and an Evaluator.
    # We use a ParamGridBuilder to construct a grid of parameters to search over.
    # With 3 values for log_reg.regParam ($\lambda$) and 3 values for log_reg.elasticNetParam ($\alpha$),
    # this grid will have 3 x 3 = 9 parameter settings for CrossValidator to choose from.
    param_grid = ParamGridBuilder()\
    .addGrid(log_reg.regParam, [0.0, 0.05, 0.1]) \
    .addGrid(log_reg.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]) \
    .build()
    
    cross_val = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline, 
                               estimatorParamMaps=param_grid,
                               evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(metricName="areaUnderROC"), # default = "areaUnderROC", alternatively "areaUnderPR"
                               numFolds=k_fold,
                               collectSubModels=True # this flag allows us to store ALL the models trained during k-fold cross validation
                               )

    # Run cross-validation, and choose the best set of parameters.
    cv_model = cross_val.fit(train)

    return cv_model


from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidatorModel
cv_model = lr_pipeline(train_df, "word2vect", "label")
```

When I go to do the model summary:

```
training_result = cv_model.bestModel.stages[-1].summary
```

to take the best result obtained from the k-fold I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-27-923b8532c6cf> in <module>()
      1 # `bestModel` is the best resulting model according to k-fold cross validation, which is also entirely retrained on the whole `train_df`
----> 2 training_result = cv_model.bestModel.stages[-1].summary
      3 print("***** Training Set *****")
      4 print("Area Under ROC Curve (ROC AUC): {:.3f}".format(training_result.areaUnderROC))
      5 print("***** Training Set *****")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/classification.py in summary(self)
   1250         else:
   1251             raise RuntimeError("No training summary available for this %s" %
-> 1252                                self.__class__.__name__)
   1253 
   1254     def evaluate(self, dataset):

RuntimeError: No training summary available for this LogisticRegressionModel
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what spark version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.1.2 @AdibP

Comment: This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61587276/9477843) might be of some help to you

Comment: Please show us how to create a minimal `train_df`, read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples

Comment: There is a spark version of the code that can be implemented:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696378/spark-linearregressionsummary-normal-summary

Comment: Please provide a sample df that you are using. I tried the example here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator.html and cvModel.bestModel.stages[-1].summary.areaUnderROC works good. I use 3.1.2 version as well.

Comment: According to the source code from here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/classification.html , summary(self) gets summary (e.g. residuals, mse, r-squared ) of model on training set. An exception is thrown if trainingSummary is None. This could be pertaining  to the data that you are using. Cos the rest of your code looks fine and it works when I did with a simple example.